# How do you get python programs to run when you type them in mingw64-win?

Tags: python, mingw-w64

I'm following a build process within mingw-w64.

Contains several instructions to type a python file which is on $PATH.

How do I set up mingw-w64 to allow that? Currently I need to type python3 followed by the full path of the py file.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104273/how-to-set-aliases-in-the-git-bash-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line (= first line starting with `#!`) is not supported in Windows, so you have to call the python executable with the script as first argument (and any arguments after that).